# Use CSS to render input form placeholder attribute from label text

Tags: html, css, forms

Given the form code below, Is it possible to populate placeholder attributes for the form input fields by reading in the text of the adjacent label

Raw html

```
<div class="mc-field-group">
<label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address</label>
<input type="email" value name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
</div>
```

Effective desired output after CSS conversion

```
<div class="mc-field-group">
<label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address</label>
<input type="email" value name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="Email Address">
</div>
```

In other words, I want to use CSS (perhaps generated content) to dynamically add a placeholder attribute on the input and make the value of the placeholder attribute reflect the label text (or hardcoded text if reading in the label text is beyond CSS)

Comment: you can't with only css

Answer (score 0):

CSS cannot modify HTML, so this is not possible.

Generated content, as the name implies, refers to content, not attributes, so it cannot be used to add or modify attributes either.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you don't want to use Javascript/Jquery for this, but if you change your mind it would be very simple to do.

```
<div class="mc-field-group">
    <label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address</label>
    <input type="email" value name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
</div>
```

then with jquery you could use this:

```
var labelText = $('label').html();
$('#mce-EMAIL').attr('placeholder', labelText);
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5kkZH/)